# Числа в обьекте

Tags: javascript

Почему в объекте нельзя хранить числа?

В массиве их хранить можно,но массив это по сути, тот же самый объект.

```js
let range = {1,2,3};  //Ошибка(((
alert(range);
```

Comment: Для данной задачи нужен массив, а не объект. [1,2,3]

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в вашем примере происходит не потому, что в объекте нельзя хранить числа.

В объекте можно хранить числа в качестве значений. Также, можно использовать числа в качестве ключей, просто они будут автоматически преобразованы в строки:

```js
console.log({ 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3 });
```

Однако вы используете краткую нотацию записи литералов. Запись вида:

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 1;

const object = { a, b };
```

по сути означает:

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 1;

const object = {
  // найти переменную a, создать ключ 'a' и присвоить ему значение переменной a,
  // найти переменную b, создать ключ 'b' и присвоить ему значение переменной b,
};
```

И когда вы пишете `let range = {1,2,3};` — у вас сразу две проблемы: во-первых, имена переменных в JS не могут начинаться с чисел, поэтому сразу происходит синтаксическая ошибка: запятая после числа заставляет воспринимать его как имя переменной, а это невозможно. Во-вторых, если бы первой ошибки не было, такие переменные всё равно не были бы найдены, так как вы их не объявляли.

Answer (score 1):

Можно хранить числа. Но в объекте своя логика хранения данных. И он предусматривает хранение данных в виде `ключ => значение`. Потому что все объекты имеют свойства и их данные, например объект человек, имеет ноги и их количество. Дом имеет окна и их количество и т.д. Но, как исключение, ключом может выступать и числа.

Простое хранение чисел в объекте - неподходящая логика и неправильное использование типов))

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в качестве ключа должна выступать строка:

```js
{one:1, two:2, three:3}
```

или

```js
{'1': 1, '2': 2,'3': 3}
```

Comment: То есть должно быть так:
let range = {one:1, two:2, three:3};
??

Comment: Или так: 
let range = {'1': 1, '2': 2,'3': 3};
console.log(range);
 {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}

Comment: "Потому что в качестве ключа должна выступать строка:" --- вообще-то нет.